# Accessing Variables in Raw PHP POST Data

Tags: php, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse Json in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parse-json-in-php)

I am working with an API that sends a POST request to my PHP script when a user performs an action. I can easily log the raw POST data to a file, for example:

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$all = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . " " . $rawPostData . "\r\n";
file_put_contents("Activity.log", $all, FILE_APPEND);
```

Writes this to the log file:

```
October 1, 2012, 12:34 pm [{"changed_aspect": "media", "subscription_id": 2421759, "object": "user", "object_id": "931456", "time": 1349120084}]
```

The only thing I am interested in is the object_id value. How can I access this value in the raw POST data? I've tried a ton and searched a number of forums for a solution. It seems simple enough but I can't seem to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: that looks like valid JSON data. You should be able to just remove everything before the first `[` and then json_decode the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post data is JSON so use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an array containing anobject and access the `object_id` property

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($rawPostData);
$json = $json[0];
$all = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . " " . $json->object_id. "\r\n";
file_put_contents("Activity.log", $all, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. The $json = $json[0] was the trick. I was trying to log $json[0]->object_id but that syntax just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The data returned is json:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
foreach($data as $obj) {
    echo $obj->object_id;
}
```