# Get information from Facebook Graph into php vars

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse Json in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parse-json-in-php)

I was looking for this awnser but couldnt find it... so here is the question

How can I get the information from https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX into vars, from this:

```
{
   "id": "XXXXXXX",
   "name": "Ricardo Capistran",
   "first_name": "Ricardo",
   "last_name": "Capistran",
   "username": "richycapy",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "es_LA"
}
```

Into this vars:

```
$id, $name, $firstname, $lastname, $username, $gender, $locale
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($from);
extract($data);
```

- **[JSON Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** - Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
- **[Extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)** - Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

Comment: Ok, just got it... this was the correct idea... thanks!! :D