# extract extra field value using php

Tags: php, joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse Json in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parse-json-in-php)

Im having a problem regarding this extra field value from joomla which I filtered from db.
any help how to accomplish this?
I need to split this `{"id":"18","value":"3:00pm-6:00pm"}` ang get only the value `3:00pm-6:00pm`

any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance
..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the values.

```
$json = json_decode('{"id":"18","value":"3:00pm-6:00pm"}');
echo $json['value'];
```