# How do I grab JSON output with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Ok, this is my first try with TwitchAPI. When I make the request, I get:

```
{"follows":[{"created_at":"2015-04-28T01:04:33Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/chaoticaura/follows/channels/giygaslp"},"notifications":true,"user":{"_id":54441701,"name":"chaoticaura","created_at":"2014-01-05T01:06:19Z","updated_at":"2015-04-28T14:18:50Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/chaoticaura"},"display_name":"ChaoticAura","logo":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chaoticaura-profile_image-3b6a888d174153f6-300x300.jpeg","bio":"Welcome to the House of Gaming/Crazy/Stupid ChaoticAura","type":"user"}},{"created_at":"2014-08-10T06:25:10Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/phoenix089/follows/channels/giygaslp"},"notifications":true,"user":{"_id":31004257,"name":"phoenix089","created_at":"2012-06-03T01:41:37Z","updated_at":"2015-04-22T19:58:28Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/phoenix089"},"display_name":"phoenix089","logo":null,"bio":null,"type":"user"}},{"created_at":"2014-05-10T17:41:05Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/monanniverse/follows/channels/giygaslp"},"notifications":true,"user":{"_id":30041264,"name":"monanniverse","created_at":"2012-04-25T10:45:21Z","updated_at":"2015-04-17T18:58:05Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/monanniverse"},"display_name":"Monanniverse","logo":null,"bio":null,"type":"user"}},{"created_at":"2013-04-25T01:10:57Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/princess_sarahkat/follows/channels/giygaslp"},"notifications":true,"user":{"_id":27411850,"name":"princess_sarahkat","created_at":"2012-01-13T23:45:04Z","updated_at":"2014-08-01T17:49:47Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/princess_sarahkat"},"display_name":"Princess_SarahKat","logo":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/princess_sarahkat-profile_image-5b554c88c6eb89a9-300x300.png","bio":null,"type":"user"}},{"created_at":"2012-12-04T13:43:15Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/thedaredevil717/follows/channels/giygaslp"},"notifications":true,"user":{"_id":38212339,"name":"thedaredevil717","created_at":"2012-12-04T13:41:17Z","updated_at":"2013-09-27T12:38:53Z","_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/thedaredevil717"},"display_name":"Thedaredevil717","logo":null,"bio":null,"type":"user"}}],"_total":5,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=0","next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=25"}}
```

I'm told that this is a JSON Response. How do I take this information, and use it with variables in PHP?

I've made some attempts that failed, here is the code:

```
<html>
<?php $json=json_decode(file_get_contents( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?limit=1")); $currentFollower=0 ; $currentPage=0 ; $resultsPerPage=5 ;  $tableHtml=<
<<TABLE <div id="page-number-%s" style="%s">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Username:</th>
    <th>Follow Date:</th>
    <th>Type:</th>
  </tr>
  %s
</table>
</div>
TABLE; $rowHtml =
<<<ROW <tr>
  <td><a href="%s">%s</a>
  </td>
  <td>%s</td>
  <td>%s</td>
  </tr>
  ROW; $html = ""; $rows = ""; foreach ($json->follows as $follow) { if ($currentFollower % $resultsPerPage == 0 && $currentFollower> 0) { $style = $currentPage === 0 ? '' : 'display:none'; $html .= sprintf($tableHtml, $currentPage, $style, $rows); $rows
  = ""; $currentPage++; } $rows .= sprintf( $rowHtml, $follow->user->_links->self, $follow->user->name . ' (' . $currentFollower . ')', $follow->user->created_at, $follow->user->type ); $currentFollower++; } $html .=
  <<<BUTTONS <button onclick="previousPage()">previous</button>
    <button onclick="nextPage()">next</button>

    BUTTONS; $javascript =
    <<<JS <script>
      var currentPage = 0; function previousPage() { if(currentPage > 0) { document.getElementById('page-number-'+currentPage).style.display = 'none'; currentPage--; document.getElementById('page-number-'+currentPage).style.display = ''; } }; function nextPage()
      { if(currentPage
      < {$currentPage} - 1) { document.getElementById( 'page-number-'+currentPage).style.display='none' ; currentPage++; document.getElementById( 'page-number-'+currentPage).style.display='' ; } }; </script>
        JS; echo $javascript.$html; ?>

</html>
```

That doesn't work though... any ideas?

Edit:
Im using this at the moment for testing

```
<html>
<script>
  <? php
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?limit=25"), true);
  print $json['follows'];
  var_dump($json['follows']) ?>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is the link with the raw JSON Output: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?limit=25

Comment: @Chaotily `j son_decode`? what's with the space?

Comment: Oh thats a typo, its correct in the code

`<html>
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?limit=1"));
`

Comment: sometimes `$json->{'follows'}` works.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `json_decode` is a bit confusing. It returns an [stdClass](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass). Add the `true` option to get a regular PHP [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents( "http://myurl.com"), true);

var_dump($json['follows']); //var_dump is print for arrays
```

---

I've found that sometimes when using stdClasses, you have to use the  key as a string:

```
$json->{'follows'}
```

---

Test your code at [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org)

Comment: So where would I put that?

Comment: @Chaoticly You can replace the `json_decode` line with this one. You can also replace all the `$json->abc` with `$json['abc']`

Comment: I do all that, and I get this
`<html>
<script>
Array</script>
</html>
`

Comment: @Chaoticly ah, you have to do `var_dump($json['follows'])`. `var_dump` is like `print` for arrays

Comment: I have the array, now how do I print it and use it for a normal website? For example, making a table, and using it in html?

Comment: That's JavaScript, you can actually do: `var javascriptJson = <?=file_get_contents( "http://myurl.com") ?>`

Comment: Sorry for extending this so much in the comments, the website is starting to get mad... Where would I put this? I tried putting it in the <php? tag but I just get parse errors

Comment: @Chaoticly put in in a <script> tag in html. You shouldn't *really* make tables with PHP, give me a second and I'll update my answer to show how to build a table

Comment: I don't really _care_ what language its in, I just don't know _how_ to do so

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example [Parsing JSON object in PHP using json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode)

and here is a way to parse it.

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Comment: I've tried this:
`<html>
<script>
<?php

$url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/giygaslp/follows?limit=25';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['follows'] as $item) {
    print $item['user'];
    print ' - ';
    print $item['_id'][0]['value'];
    print ' - ';
    print '<img src="' . $item['logo'][0]['value'] . '" border="0" alt="" />';
    print '<br>';
}
</script>
</html>
`
With no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that JSON data to an array which you can easily use with PHP.  To do this use PHP's `json_decode()` function.

```
$decodedJSON = json_decode($JSON, true);
```

It's important you pass in `true` as the second parameter otherwise you will not get an array back.

Now that you have an array you can access elements from that JSON data in that array.  For example:

```
$decodedJSON[key]
```

In the above example, `key` can be any key that was in the JSON data we converted and it will return whatever value belongs to that key.