# fetch a list of business types from a JSON API call. and include them in a select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Revision on this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://yoco-core-staging.herokuapp.com/api/common/v1/properties/businessCategories';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

?>

<select>

<?php 

foreach($json['data'] as $item) {
    print '<option>'.$item[2].'</option>';
}

?>

</select>
```

This is the new code that I have inputted to get the select statement to show these options. All I must do now is create a function to eliminate duplicate entries and then bam done!

Thank you for all the help and comments

Comment: You can use `PHP` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode

Comment: what is your exactly need?

Comment: I think it is a bit unclear what you expect from the end result, would you rather use `jQuery` or `PHP`?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Updated question. I would rather use PHP if possible.I am looking to create a select menu in html, with food and drink as one of my options, I need the API call to dynamically generate more options as they are inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try this. this is print all the data that return your JSON.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://yoco-core-staging.herokuapp.com/api/common/v1/properties/businessCategories';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['data'] as $item) {
    print $item[0];
    print $item[1];
    print $item[2];
    print '<br>';
}
```

Comment: You have just become the coolest person in the entire world in my eyes.. Even cooler than that guy from Pearl Jam. Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

The group reference you're using in your code is not identified as a field name in the JSON object, hence why you get the undefined error.

The JSON object is returned as followed:

```
    array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  int(200)
  ["data"]=>
  array(122) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "5462"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Bakery"
      [2]=>
      string(27) "Food, drink and hospitality"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "5813"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "Bar"
      [2]=>
      string(27) "Food, drink and hospitality"
    }
    [2]=>
```

You can just loop through the object by using the number reference the object returns.
For your case, you can just echo $json[data][1] & $json[data][2] foreach object.

Answer (score -1):

[Please add a comment before downvoting]

You can do somthing like this:

```
$.ajax({        
       url: 'http://yoco-core-staging.herokuapp.com/api/common/v1/properties/businessCategories',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(data, status) {
        //data = JSON.parse(data); this is optional depending on the type you are getting from the server
        var len = data.length;
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var id = data[i].Id;
            var title = data[i].title;
            var group = data[i].group;
            html += '<li>'+id+' - '+title+' - '+group+'</li>';
        }
        $('#somecontainer').html('<ul>'+html+'</ul>');

       },
       error: function(e) {
           console.log(e);             
       }
   });
```

I dont know the names of the fields but this is basicly it

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP is clearly using HTML selects created by PHP (yes i know they also tagged this jquery+javascript) and you've replaced that with a completely jquery system that now uses an unordered list over selects with no explanation as to why the OP should use this method or what it all means.  TBH, the question actually mentions 'select menu' specifically.