# Fetch Data that sent from android application with the help of JSONObject

Tags: php, android

Hello all I am creating an android application and using HttpURLConnection Class. Here urlConn is object of HttpURLConnection class.
`JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();`
`jo.put("name","xyz");`
`jo.put("email","xyz@abc.com")`

I am sending this using..

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
out.write(jo.toString());
out.close();
```

Now i want to fetch this data into php page that i have hosted online.
So please tell me how to fetch JSONObject data in to php page.

Answer (score 0):

Read about json decode :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

SO dicsussion :

[Parsing JSON object in PHP using json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode)

Comment: I have tried but didn't able to get.
I want to fetch this variables and store in to separate variable in to php script then want to store into Database.
I want output like this $name = xyz
                                  $email = xyz@abc.com in php.