# Record the result of a curl GET request using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm trying to understand how to record the result of a curl GET request using php. I'm looking at outputing part or all of the result to mysql.

https://github.com/cloudtrax/docs/blob/master/api/code/php/simple_api_server_test_harness.php

```
function invoke_curl($method, $endpoint, $headers, $json) {
$api_server = 'https://api.cloudtrax.com';
try {
    // get a curl handle then go to town on it
    $ch = curl_init($api_server . $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result == FALSE) {
        if (curl_errno($ch) == 0)
            echo "@@@@ NOTE @@@@: nil HTTP return: This API call appears to be broken" . "\n";
        else
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));    
    }
    else
      echo "RESULT: \n" . $result . "\n";
}
```

The $result shows like this:

```
{
    "clients": {
        "ssid2": 4,
        "ssid1": 10
    },
    "rows": [
        {
            "time": "2016-03-23T02:45:00Z",
            "ssid2": {
                "traffic": {
                    "unclassified": {
//  etc...
```

How can I associate each part of the result too a variable so I can then input too mysql?

Comment: none of the answers do the job, @shagun akarsh those links got me closer, but my guess is there is something about the 'depth' of the json which needs to be ordered better. I mean the "clients" is 1 level, then "rows" has its own structure then 'time' has 24 results under 'ssid1' and 'ssid2'

Comment: progress thanks guys: `
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($result, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
echo "<br>";
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
  echo "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
  echo "<br>";
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this result in json format. You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it:

```
$resultObject = json_decode($result);
$clients = $resultObject->clients;
// ... get other data from result
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will convert the json into a PHP array. You can then use the indexes of the array to pull out values.

```
$result = json_decode($result);
$clients = $result->clients;
// Some MySQL queries
```

Answer (score 0):

If your response is a JSON response then you can simply use php's json_decode to get parsed object.

```
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 //to get associative array passing true
 $jsonObj = json_decode($result, true);

 $clients = $jsonObj['clients'];
 $rows = $jsonObj['rows'];
```

You can refer to these answers for more detail: 
[Parsing JSON object in PHP using json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode) and 
[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)