# Counting json data using php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

just need to get a specific count of a json data

here's the sample json format:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json",
      "id": 1,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "open",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
      "id": 2,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "close",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
      "id": 2,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "solve",
    }
    ]
}
```

i want to count how many open, close and solve status using php or ajax or both... need the data auto load also... so we don't need to refresh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
var jsonObject = {
  "tickets": [
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json",
      "id": 1,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "open",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json",
      "id": 1,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "open",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
      "id": 2,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "close",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://asd.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/2.json",
      "id": 2,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "sample_ticket",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-04-25T05:56:36Z",
      "status": "solve",
    }
    ]
};

var open = 0, close = 0; solve = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < jsonObject.tickets.length; i++)
{
  if(jsonObject.tickets[i].status == "open")
  {
   open++;
  }
  else if(jsonObject.tickets[i].status == "close")
  {
   close++;
  }
  else if(jsonObject.tickets[i].status == "solve")
  {
   solve++;
  }

}

console.log(open, close, solve);
```

Comment: You can use `json_decode`, the json will then be treated as a php array. Then you can apply the same concept to count the occurrence with values. Check this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035742/parsing-json-object-in-php-using-json-decode